What does "go" in "can't go" refer to?
In Loving Vincent (2017), Vincent wrote a letter to Mr. Theo Van Gogh before dying. Joseph tried to
post it but it was undeliverable. He asks Armand to find Mr. Theo and deliver
the letter, advising him to start the conversation with condolences for the loss:

Joseph: Let's get you sobered up.
Armand: I can't go it's too late.

What does "go" in "can't go" refer to?

In the context you describe, presumably he means 'I can't go to look for Theo right now'. What  else?

@KateBunting Will you convert that note to answer?

You say: He asks Armand to find Mr. Theo and deliver the letter.
Therefore, it's fairly obvious that Armand must mean "I can't go to look for Theo right now". (I assume he means 'too late in the day' rather than 'too late to be of any use.)
